# Forcing eager evaluation of a Haskell list

Tags: haskell, recursion, lazy-evaluation

Going over the "Learn yourself..." book I encountered a BMI calculator app. The app, so far, takes a list of pairs of Double and returns a list of Double:

```
calcBMI :: [(Double, Double)] -> [Dobule]
calcBMI xs = [bmi w h | (w, h) <- xs]
    where bmi weight height = weight / height ^ 2
```

Trying to apply another function to each element of the returned list I tried `map declareBMI head calcBMI [(w, h) | w <- [60..70], h <- [1.65]]` but got an error (where `declareBMI` was defined):

```
declareBMI :: Double -> String
declareBMI bmi
    | bmi <= 18.5 = "Skinny"
    | bmi <= 25 = "Norm"
    | bmi <=30 = "Overweight"
    | otherwise = "OBESE!"
```

After viewing the definition of `map` (i.e. `map f x:xs = f x : map f xs`) I figured out the problem: I'm trying to call `head` on the remainder of a **lazy** list, meaning the interpreter tries to **first** run `calcBMI` and only then `head`-ing the result... and this will of course fail because `calcBMI` requires a list of pairs.

So, my question is

1. is there a way to force an eager evaluation of the `calcBMI` function so I can run `head` on the resultant list?
2. Is there a **better way** then forcing eager evaluation to allow me to `head` each element of the resultant list?

Comment: `map head calcBMI [(w, h) | w <- [60..70], h <- [1.65]]` is just ill-typed, so laziness isn't particularly relevant here. Also, the list resulting from `calcBMI` has type `[Double]`, so it's not possible to `head` each element, because `head` works on lists and `Double`-s aren't lists. Could you clarify what functionality you'd like to achieve?

Comment: Hi. The result I'd like to get is that I run another function, say `declareBMI` that takes the numeric value `calcBMI` computed and outputs a string saying "You're OK", "You're fat", etc. To the best of my understanding `calcBMI` as I defined it returns a list of Double: `[Double]`. I can see why `map head` won't work... now that I think about it, but I also tried: `map declareBMI head calcBMI...` and it failed too.

Comment: Rethinking my code I see why `map` is **not** the right way to go, starting from the second element there's nothing to `head`, it is ill-typed as Andras Kovacs states! So, I'm now at a complete loss as to how to generate the list of declarations from the list of doubles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the types line up. If you're unsure about types or get compiler errors, try to break up your code into smaller expressions and use GHCi or [TypedHoles](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/typed-holes.html) to inspect types.

An example GHCi session:

```
> let xs = [(w, h) | w <- [60..70], h <- [1.65]]
> :t calcBMI xs
calcBMI xs :: [Double]
```

Here we asked the type of `calcBMI xs`, and got `[Double]` as expected.

Now we can take the first element of `calcBMI xs` using `head`:

```
> head (calcBMI xs)
22.03856749311295
```

We can use `head` because its input is a list, and `calcBMI xs` is a list.

```
> :t head
head :: [a] -> a
```

`declareBMI` has type `Double -> String`, so we can use it on plain `Double` values, but we can also use it on values inside lists with `map`.

```
> let bmis = calcBMI xs
> declareBMI (head bmis)
"Norm"
```

Here we used `declareBMI` on a `Double`. We could also first use `declareBMI` on on the list elements, and apply `head` afterwards.

```
> :t map declareBMI bmis
map declareBMI bmis :: [String]
> map declareBMI bmis
["Norm","Norm","Norm","Norm","Norm","Norm","Norm","Norm","Norm","Overweight","Overweight"]
> head (map declareBMI bmis)
"Norm"
```

Also, don't forget that in Haskell we apply functions just by whitespace. So `head (map declareBMI bmis)` is correct, because `map` takes two arguments here, and `head` takes one. We don't parenthesize function calls, but rather individual arguments to a function.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much. Thanks for walking me through it, not just putting some code and letting me figure it out. Also, comment about parenthesis -- taken to heart.